# Перебор в числе С++

Tags: c++

Есть число **2098216**. Надо найти количество трехзначных чисел, которые можно создать из цифр этого числа, т.е. **209, 982, 821, 216.**

Можно ли это сделать с помощью алгоритма `next_premutation`? Если нет, то помогите найти другой метод.

Comment: Тема "Бином Ньютона"? А 229 не число?

Comment: нет нельзя. Этот алгоритм для перестановок сделан.

Comment: @goodalien  При чем здесь перестановки? И что вы в действительности хотите получить в качестве результата: только число трехзначных чисел состоящих из смежных цифр исходного числа?

Comment: *Надо найти количество трехзначных чисел, которые можно создать из цифр этого числа, т.е. 209, 982, 821, 216.*

Что-то мне кажется, что из этих цифр можно получить и 202, и 610, например. Если нет - то у вас неверно сформулирована задача.

Comment: И, если нужны только смежные числа, то нужны ли числа 162 и 620? И в обратную сторону по кольцу: 902, 890 и так далее.

Comment: Имхо, наличие точки после 216 вместо многоточия, говорит о том, что пример контрольный, и эти 4 числа - полное множество удовлетворяющее условию. Так ли это?

Comment: Во, и ещё: следует ли считать дубликаты? `121212` => `{121, 212} => 2`?

Comment: Резюмируя все замечания: пока нет точного ТЗ - результат ХЗ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

идея алгоритма - рассматриваем число наоборот, каждый раз показывая последние три цифры и отбрасывая последнюю

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int calc(int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    while (n > 99) {
        int c = n % 1000;
        if (c > 99) {
            cout << c << endl; // закоментировать, если числа не нужны
            total++;
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return total;
}

int main() {
    int n = 2098216;
    cout << "total " << calc(n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Эту же задачу можно решить и через строковое представление, но мне кажется, это будет переусложнение.

Comment: А ему не вывести их надо, а просто количество подсчитать.

Comment: поправил, что бы было так.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть число 2098216. Надо найти количество трехзначных чисел, которые можно создать из цифр этого числа, т.е. 209, 982, 821, 216

Все гораздо проще. Если бы не цифра "нуль", то можно было бы вычислять "выборку с возвращением". В данном же случае можно поступить так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int Calc3(int D) {
  int V[10] = {0};
  for(;D>0;D/=10) V[D%10]=1;
  int N = std::accumulate(std::begin(V),std::end(V),0);
  return (N-V[0])*N*N;
}

int main () {
  std::cout << Calc3(2098216) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
180
```

[На ideone](http://ideone.com/PCMFwG).

**Объяснение решения**

- находим "алфавит", иными словами число уникальных цифр N
- первый разряд трехзначного числа может принимать N-1 значений, т.к. в цифрах есть нуль
- остальные разряды трехзначного числа могут принимать N значений каждый

Вывод: число комбинаций равно (N-1) * N * N

Comment: А разве в контрольном примере ответ не 4?

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос "Надо найти количество трехзначных чисел, которые можно создать из цифр этого числа". Пример - число 892. Если там действительно пример контрольный, то как объяснить отсутствие этого числа в том контрольном примере?

Comment: В вопросе не указан способ создания числа, способ указан в контрольном примере. Это создание числа из смежных цифр без перестановок. (Разумеется может быть и не так, мы не можем знать точно =) )

Comment: Значит вопрос нужно формулировать полно, а не задавать ребусы.

Comment: Вы допускаете, например, 999, а его нельзя создать - в числе только одна цифра 9...

Comment: Читаем "создать из цифр" - я понял это как "множество доступных цифр". В моем понимании - можно.